# How do I add constant values in a row for each new column value?

Tags: sql, excel, sas

I have data that looks like this:

```
number    letter
1          a
1          b
1          c
2          d
2          e
3          f
3          g
3          h
3          i
```

I want to insert 3 new rows (x,y,z) at each new value in the "number" field, so that it looks like this:

```
number    letter
1          a
1          b
1          c
1          x
1          y
1          z
2          d
2          e
2          x
2          y
2          z
3          f
3          g
3          h
3          i
3          x
3          y
3          z
```

Help?

Comment: The answer in SQL will differ from the answer in SAS will differ from the answer in Excel.  What do you want??

Comment: Understood - happy to receive an answer in any of the above, which is why I tagged all :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In SAS you could just add some OUTPUT statements to your data step.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by number;
  output;
  if last.number then do letter='x','y','z';
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this in SQL.  The following should work in just about any database:

```
select number, letter
from t
union all
select distinct number, 'x' 
from t
union all
select distinct number, 'y' 
from t
union all
select distinct number, 'z' 
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

In proc Sql you can do a cross join followed by union as shown below;

```
data have1;
input id val$;
datalines;
1          a
1          b
1          c
2          d
2          e
3          f
3          g
3          h
3          i
;
run;

data have2;
input val $;
datalines;
x
y
z
;
proc sql;
create table want as 
select * from have1
union 
select id, val from 
(select distinct id from have1)a
cross join 
(select val from have2)b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Data step solution instead of SQL. 
Use an explicit `OUTPUT` statement to control the output.

```
data have;
    input id val$;
    datalines;
1          a
1          b
1          c
2          d
2          e
3          f
3          g
3          h
3          i
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by id;
    output;

    if last.id then
        do;

            do val='x', 'y', 'z';
                output;
            end;
        end;
run;
```